# Constraining between two recursive many-to-many relationships

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many, data-modeling

I have the following tables for creating any number of items with different types.

```
CREATE TABLE item_types (
    id SERIAL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -- Other columns omitted
);

CREATE TABLE items (
    id SERIAL,
    itemtype integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (itemtype) REFERENCES item_types (id)
    -- Other columns omitted
);
```

The `items` table has a recursive many-to-many relationship called `item_relationship`.

```
CREATE TABLE item_relationships (
    itemid1 integer,
    itemid2 integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (itemid1, itemid2),
    FOREIGN KEY (itemid1) REFERENCES items (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (itemid2) REFERENCES items (id) 
);
```

The `item_types` table has a recursive many-to-many relationship called `item_relationship_types`.

```
CREATE TABLE item_relationship_types (
    type1 integer,
    type2 integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (type1, type2),
    FOREIGN KEY (type1) REFERENCES item_types (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (type2) REFERENCES item_types (id)  
);
```

Now, what I want to do is to somehow have a constraint that you can't accidentally create an `item_relationship` that is invalid, i.e where the `item_types` of the items are not found in any `item_relationship_type`. I have two questions.

1. Does such a constraint make sense? I think inserting a wrong relationship is a mistake that could easily happen in business logic, so constraining in the DB feels important.
2. What's the sensible way to actually implement the constraint?

Comment: Note: there is no recursion involved here; this is a kind of *model->instance* inheritance pattern.

Comment: What exactly does "recursive" mean ? When for example the table `item_relationship_types` has the following records: `(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)`, does it mean that type 1 is related not only to type 2, but also to 3 and 4 ?

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @kordirko in your example 1 is related indirectly to 3 and 4, but creating an item_relationship between items of type (1,3) and (1,4) should not be possible. Only between the ones you listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible approach could be extending `item_relationship_types` table with a surrogate primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE item_relationship_types (
    id integer SERIAL,
    type1 integer,
    type2 integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE (type1, type2),
    FOREIGN KEY (type1) REFERENCES item_types (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (type2) REFERENCES item_types (id)  
);
```

and then add a foreign key pointing to that surrogate key into `item_relationships` table:

```
CREATE TABLE item_relationships (
    itemid1 integer,
    itemid2 integer,
    type_rel_id integer not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (itemid1, itemid2),
    FOREIGN KEY (itemid1) REFERENCES items (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (itemid2) REFERENCES items (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (type_rel_id) REFERENCES item_relationship_types (id)  
);
```

You need also create a trigger that prevents from entering `type_rel_id` value in `item_relationships` table that points to the entry with types not related to these two items in `item_relationship_types` table.

Comment: I tried the trigger variant but it proved to be too slow. I expanded on your idea and instead of creating a surrogate key I added `type1` and `type2` from `item_relationship_types` directly to `item_relationships`. In `item_relationships` I added `FOREIGN KEY (type1, itemid1) REFERENCES items (itemtype, id)` and same for `type2` and `itemid2`. Then I added `FOREIGN KEY (type1, type2) REFERENCES item_relation_types (type1, type2)`. This takes care of the constraints efficiently, but something feels off about having to add `type1` and `type2` to `item_relations`. Any thoughts on this solution?

Answer (score 1):

- this is not perfect, but it appears to work

---

```
CREATE FUNCTION item_check_types( ) RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM item_relationship_types irt
        JOIN items it1 ON it1.itemtype = irt.type1
        JOIN items it2 ON it2.itemtype = irt.type2
        WHERE (it1.id = NEW.itemid1 AND it2.id = NEW.itemid2)
        -- OR (it1.id = NEW.itemid2 AND it2.id = NEW.itemid1)
        ) THEN RETURN NEW;
ELSE
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'type lookup failure';
        RETURN NULL;
END IF;

END;
$func$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
        ;

CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER item_check_types
        AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT
        -- BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT
        ON item_relationships
        FOR EACH ROW
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE item_check_types()
        ;

INSERT INTO item_types(id)
SELECT generate_series(1,10);

INSERT INTO item_relationship_types (type1, type2) VALUES
(1,3), (2,4), (3,5), (4,6);

INSERT INTO items(id, itemtype)
SELECT gs, gs % 10
FROM generate_series(101,109) gs;

INSERT INTO item_relationships(itemid1, itemid2)
  VALUES (101,103), (102,104); -- Okay
INSERT INTO item_relationships(itemid1, itemid2)
  VALUES (101,104), (102,103); -- should fail
```

Comment: What if someone deletes a record from `item_relationship_types` without deleting a corresponding row from `item_relationships`? The integrity will be broken.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to handle that case, too. (unfortunately, cascading is impossible here)

Comment: @D4rt I rolled back to the original version. It appears to be cirrect.

Comment: You are comparing `items (id)` to `item_types (id)`. The values in `items (id)` range from 101 to 109, in `item_types (id)` from 1 to 9, so they never match. Your code failed on both inserts.

Comment: Here the first pair of inserts succeeds, the second pair fails, as expected. I'll look into it again.